# Как сделать простейшую парольную защиту РНР скрипта?

Tags: php

В общем, я уже задавал этот вопрос, но его удаляли, ссылаясь на похожие, но суть тут совсем другая.
Представьте, что у меня есть личный сайт. Любительский такой, где я пишу блог, выкладываю разную информацию и т.д. И на нем среди прочего есть строка "Секретный портал". При нажатии на нее выходит форма с полем ввода и кнопкой. Если правильно ввести пароль в поле ввода и нажать кнопку, можно перейти на страницу, где я выкладываю уж очень личную информацию. Я, разумеется, не хочу, чтобы ее просматривало мое начальство и прочие люди, поэтому пароль даю самым проверенным друзьям. Они переходят, смотрят, но тут возникает проблема: кто-то из них по какой-то причине хочет обновить страничку, нажимает F5, и сверху выскакивает проклятая табличка: "На странице, которую вы ищете, использовалась введенная вами информация. При возврате на эту страницу может потребоваться повторить выполненные ранее действия. Продолжить?" Эта табличка преследует моих друзей, выскакивая каждый раз, когда они нажимают F5. Друзья в шоке. Придя на работу, они рассказывают всем об этом, весь коллектив лежит на полу, насмехаясь надо мной, а начальство, узнав, что у них такой растяпа-работник, увольняет меня.
Я уже всячески пытался решить эту проблему, но ничего не выходит.
Вот код моей формы:

```
<form action="info.php" method="post">

  <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль">
  <input type="submit" value="Кнопка">

</form>
```

А вот код страницы info.php:

```
<?
    if (isset($_POST["password"])){  
        header('location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        exit();
    }
?>
    Содержимое
```

Я уже пытался убрать header('location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);, но тогда содержимое страницы не загружается, пытался убрать exit();, но тогда я даже не могу перейти на эту страницу. Как избавиться от ненавистной выскакивающей таблички? В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Ну вот отпять только минусуют, и ни одного ответа. Неужели такой глупый вопрос? Так подскажите, как его решить. А тут только то советуют обратиться в google.com, то учить мат часть, то и вовсе блокируют вопрос. Я, конечно, понимаю, что надо лопатить учебники, и я не против этого, но ради одной только этой штучки тратить месяцы? Для чего тогда нужен форум?

Comment: И этот закроют.

Comment: По какой же причине?

Comment: По той же что и все остальные.

Comment: То есть это какая-то запретная тема, табу, секрет фирмы, и отвечать на него нельзя?

Comment: Нет, тема не запретная. А вопрос дурацкий. Он явно выдуман из головы, и в нем перемешаны две совершенно несвязанные между собой темы - **авторизация**, которая к редиректам вообще никакого отношения не имеет, и повторная отправка формы, которая лечится простейшим редиректом. Чтобы вопрос не закрыли, он должен быть осмысленным, однозначным, и описывать реальную проблему, а не вымышленную

Comment: В смысле вымышленный вопрос? Код я полностью привел. Он небольшой, можете скопировать его к себе и запустить, получится та же проблема. Какой смысл мне что-то придумывать? Я согласен, что в php разбираюсь плохо, но я учусь, и в данный момент передо мной встала вот такая проблема, которую я уже который день не могу решить. Именно поэтому я и решил спросить об этом у людей, которые в этом что-то понимают. Но эти люди без объяснения причин минусуют, и ни один из них ещё не сказал, как реализовать мою задачу. В этом случае возникает вопрос: для чего создавался форум? Чтобы помочь или поиздеваться?

Comment: Stack overflow - это не форум.

Comment: Это система вопросов. Вот я и спрашиваю. Если бы я был гуру-программистом, разумеется, меня бы здесь не было. А PHP я изучаю только месяц.

Comment: Так если спрашиваете, то научитесь сначала гуглить. Инфы по всему этому валом (и даже здесь явно что-то было). Незнание правил не освобождает от ответственности.

Comment: Все, что я находил, это размытые абстрактные простыни текста. А мне всего-то надо: при нажатии кнопки переходить на новую страницу, чтобы при этом обновлялся мой запрос. И ни один не предложил решения. Вместо этого только спрашивают, а зачем я это делаю через форму, а не через ссылку, а для чего вообще нужна такая штуковина на сайте, для чего вводить пароль и проч, приплетут какие-то базы данных для хранения паролей, а потом, когда я потрачу часы и часы на объяснение, что я хочу сделать, они бесследно пропадают. Другие просто минусят без причин.

Answer (score 0):

1. убираешь весь этот детский сад с формами, редиректами и отсутствием проверки пароля
2. добавляешь в начало своей супер-секретной страницы

   ```
   if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) OR $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] !== 'secret' OR $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] !== 'assword'){
       Header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected"');
       Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
       exit;
   }
   ```

не забыв поменять 'secret' и 'assword' на свои собственные значения